# Data Validation with filter

Tags: excel, vba

I am aware of how to create a combobox to emulate a data validation cell based off of a range list, featuring the ability to filter the dropdown list based on what you type in. This is similar in functionality to how column filtering in an Excel table works, where if I start typing "tor" it will immediately filter the preview window for items only containing the string "tor".

However, I am trying to create a report where every row requires the same dropdown menu, and ideally what I hope to do is have each row have this cell where you can click on the dropdown, start typing, and the list will narrow down. However, I realize a combobox is a unique object and it cannot be duplicated as simply as copying and inserting a row with a data validation field.

Is there a way I can easily duplicate this sort of drop down where a list preview filters based on what is typed into the cell, either via vba or plain data validation? In short, can a dropdown with the filtering preview capability as my code below be copied and pasted as easily as a simple data validated cell within a row?

For reference here is my combobox code, listing range A2:A791 on sheet DVTest:

```
Sub ComboBox1_Populate(Optional fltr As String)
ComboBox1.List = 
Filter(Application.Transpose(Worksheets("DVTest").Range("A2:A791" & 
SymbolCount).Value), fltr)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal 
Shift As Integer)
Call ComboBox1_Populate(ComboBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Call ComboBox1_Populate
End Sub
```

Thanks kindly!

Comment: Do you know how many rows will ultimately need a combobox or are you just looking for something that will work with an arbitrary number of rows\comboboxes?

Comment: Hi Brad, it would be arbitrary. For instance, I may look to take a single reference row and copy/insert it 10 times.The number of rows will be dependent on the amount of records I download and need to allocate via the dropdown.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work, but maybe something along the lines of having an array of comboboxes that you could reference and then having generic functions that they could call do to the filtering? I'm not sure if VBA can be tortured to do such a thing, though.